# Checking if input is empty in javascript fails

Tags: javascript, input

Both in the case I enter a string and in the case I leave the input box blank, I get the console.log("Something's wrong!");
The console.log of my fieldObj is in both cases shown empty.

I tried check if the content of an input-field is empty:

CODE:

```js
let fieldObj = document.getElementById("newListItem").value;
let button = document.getElementById("addItem");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (fieldObj != "") {
    console.log(fieldObj);
    console.log("Everything ok!");
  } else {
    console.log(fieldObj);
    console.log("Something's wrong!");
  }

}, false);
```

```html
<input id="newListItem" type="text" />
<button id="addItem">Add</button>
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you set `fieldObj` as soon as the page loads, so it will be set as `""` and never change.

You need to update the value inside the click listener :

```js
const button = document.getElementById("addItem");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const fieldObj = document.getElementById("newListItem").value;
  if (fieldObj !== "") {
    console.log(fieldObj);
    console.log("Everything ok!");
  } else {
    console.log(fieldObj);
    console.log("Something's wrong!");
  }

}, false);
```

```html
<input id="newListItem" type="text" />
<button id="addItem">Add</button>
```